# Query about keys in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key

Interpreter shows no error if we use two keys of same name. By what mechanism does it decide which of the two to use while execution ?.

Comment: When you assign a value to an existing key, the previous value is not longer present, it overwrite it

Comment: Can you clarify what situation you are inquiring on? A dict literal? A comprehension? Assignment? Update? Most importantly, did you try and test?

Comment: You actually **never** use "two keys of the same name" - dict keys are unique, period (just like list indices are unique). Assigning to key replaces previous value if the key already existed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = dict()
d["a"] = "a"
d["a"] = "b"
```

The value of `a` will be overwritten and the new value will be `b`.